# Error inflating class ImageButton in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android

When I run my application it shows my Application has stopped working when I put a try block on that line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`,

It throws an exception of

```
Error inflating class ImageButton.
```

I think there is a problem in the XML code, help me to find the problem.

**Java Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("Error>>> ",e.getMessage());
    }

  }

  public void change(View view){
    ImageButton Tom= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cartoon);
    Tom.animate().alpha(0.3f).setDuration(2000);
    Tom.setImageResource(R.drawable.jerry);
  }
}
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.chhabib.animations.MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cartoon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/this_is_tom"
    android:onClick="change"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the complete exception text. Also, within your relative layout, you have the following text present: `[enter image description here][1]`. is this text also part of your layout file?

Comment: @cjurjiu off course not! and how can it be part of the layout file ?

Comment: I have edited the question, please review it @Habib so the confusion is avoided.

Comment: I executed your app, it works fine for me, check your image type.

Answer (score 1):

**I have found the solution of my problem.**
Actually I copy the images in to the drawable(v24), but when i copy the images in to drawable folder, my problem resolved. But now I am looking for the difference between the drawable folder and drawable(v24) folder.

Comment: A `drawablevX` folder will only load those resources when running on a device with `API >= X`. In your logcat window, it says `API 23`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Image source is of supported type in Android.

and Try to also put `android:src="@drawable/tom"`

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cartoon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/this_is_tom"
    android:onClick="change"
    android:src="@drawable/tom"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tom"/>
```